# How to create Data Conection Libary with option read and write

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, data

I want to create data conection library to transfer a data from MSSQL serwer to Sharepoint list and with read write option. I must edit a data from a MSSQL table to Sharepoint list.

Please help.

Comment: Looked in to BCS?

Comment: Yes and no because now I traingng this by InfoPath, because I must have got two or three tables not one table.

Comment: How could I set user permissions in BCS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Research "Creating an external list using BCS" to see if this will work for you. It should as external lists can provide read/write access to external content types, including a SQL Server database table. There are numerous examples on the web and plenty of Microsoft documentation on this topic. Many of the web examples show exactly that scenario, creating an external content type that connects to MS SQL Server.

[SharePoint Business Connectivity Services on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681491%28v=office.14%29)

[Create an External List based on a SQL Server table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee557243%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

There is even a whole book dedicated to BCS.

[Professional Business Connectivity Services](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047061790X)

Regarding your comment above about permissions, see:

[Business Connectivity Services Security Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee661743%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Because your question is not that specific, these are high-level answers to point you in the right direction so you can get started. Once you get started SharePoint StackExchange is a good resource if you get stuck or have more specific questions.

Comment: And Can I Conect MS SQL serwer table with Sharepoint list and show this conection on sharepoint another list ?

Comment: You can use external columns (slightly different than an external list). See the resources I listed above for the difference.  You can join SharePoint lists (using CAML queries) or SQL server tables (using SQL).  You can also create views in SQL Server that do the joins and then have an external content type to show that view in a list. The view lets SQL Server do the work for the joins (which it is good at).